# Detect paragraph boundaries with regex in messy text in Python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, paragraph

I have a body of text that looks like this:

`\n1. When an injunction is obtained against an innocent intermediary to prevent \nthe use of his facilities by wrongdoers for unlawful purposes, who should pay the \n\ncost of complying with the order? \n\n2. The respondents are three Swiss or German companies belonging to the \nRichemont Group. They design, manufacture and sell luxury branded goods such as \n\njewellery, watches and pens under well-known trade marks including Cartier, \n\nMontblanc and IWC. The internet has provided infringers with a powerful tool for \n\nselling counterfeit copies of branded luxury goods, generally of lower quality than \n\nthe genuine article and at lower prices. It allows them access to a world-wide market, \n\nas well as a simple way of concluding sales and collecting the price with practically \n\ncomplete anonymity. This illicit business is carried out on a large scale. The \n\nevidence is that at the outset of this litigation the respondents alone had identified \n\nsome 46,000 websites offering infringing copies of their branded goods. \n\n3. The two appellants and three other defendants in the proceedings below (who \ndid not participate in this appeal) are the five largest internet service providers (or \n\n"ISPs") serving the United Kingdom, with a combined market share exceeding 90%.`

I'm trying to segment the block into two paragraphs:

**Para 1**

`\n1. When an injunction is obtained against an innocent intermediary to prevent \nthe use of his facilities by wrongdoers for unlawful purposes, who should pay the \n\ncost of complying with the order?`

**Para 2**

`\n\n2. The respondents are three Swiss or German companies belonging to the \nRichemont Group. They design, manufacture and sell luxury branded goods such as \n\njewellery, watches and pens under well-known trade marks including Cartier, \n\nMontblanc and IWC. The internet has provided infringers with a powerful tool for \n\nselling counterfeit copies of branded luxury goods, generally of lower quality than \n\nthe genuine article and at lower prices. It allows them access to a world-wide market, \n\nas well as a simple way of concluding sales and collecting the price with practically \n\ncomplete anonymity. This illicit business is carried out on a large scale. The \n\nevidence is that at the outset of this litigation the respondents alone had identified \n\nsome 46,000 websites offering infringing copies of their branded goods. \n\n3. The two appellants and three other defendants in the proceedings below (who \ndid not participate in this appeal) are the five largest internet service providers (or \n\n"ISPs") serving the United Kingdom, with a combined market share exceeding 90%.`

I'm trying to achieve this split with a regular expression, but am struggling to get the lookahead to work properly.

I'm testing in regex101 with the following expression:

`(\\n\d+\..*)(?!\\n\\n\d+\.)`

In group 1, I'm attempting to capture the paragraph number and everything that follows up until the lookahead kicks in and stops the match at the next paragraph number. The regex is just consuming the entire block and I'm a little but uncertain where I'm going wrong. I'd be grateful for any steer in the right direction SO might be able to provide.

Demo on regex101 [here](https://regex101.com/r/s7F1hi/1)

Comment: Why not a regex split on `\\n\\n\d+`? First paragraph doesn't have the `\n` before it's `\n1`, but it is not a problem since it's first paragraph actually.

Comment: Yes, you're right. There was also a problem with the quantifier in the first group. The working regex is `\\n\\n\d+\..+?(?=\\n\\n\d+\.)`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7fCITv/1)

Comment: I was thinking on something more like this: [link](https://repl.it/repls/LightheartedOriginalAgent)